# Complexity of insertion

Tags: sorting, c++11, vector, insert

I have a sorted vector,
what is better:
using lower_bound and insert the element at its place in the vector.
or simply push_back the element into vector and sort it when it is required with sort()?

Comment: That depends on how often "when it is required" is.

Comment: I would sort when it is required. If the number of unsorted elements is small compared to the size of the vector, use an insertion sort for the last pushed back elements. Otherwise use std::sort for the last elements and then use an inplace merge.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is tagged [tag:C++11].  I don't see anything in this question that is even particularly [tag:C++]-dependent, other than `lower_bound`, `insert`, `push_back`, and `sort`, which are all in `C++03` and `C++98`.  Everything else is just generic algorithm-analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that individual operation performed once, it is cheaper to use `lower_bound` and `insert`.  `lower_bound` is `O(log(n))` and `insert` will be (worst and average case) `O(n)`, giving a final complexity of `O(n)`.

If you don't need the vector sorted until after you're done inserting into it, it will be much cheaper to sort only once, since all the `push_back`s will be `O(1)*O(n) = O(n)` and the final sort will be `O(n*log(n))`, giving you a final complexity of `O(n*log(n))`, whereas the multiple `lower_bound`+`insert` will give you a complexity of `O(n)*O(n) = O(n**2)`.

If you need the elements sorted throughout the insertion process, which one is cheaper will depend heavily on your usage pattern (how often and when you need the elements sorted).  It can often be the case that you only need the elements sorted at the end of the construction process, which is why sorting at the end can be a very powerful tool in your tool belt.  If that is not your usage pattern, you may want to at least consider using an associative container such as `multi_set` or `multi_map`.

Comment: Thank you. In my case it seeems that lower_bound and insertion provides faster performances.